# seeds.rb failing with SQLite3::ConstraintException on relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using seeds.rb to create two records, one of which belongs to the other:

```
new_account = Account.create(name: 'AccountName')
new_user = User.create(
  email: 'foo@example.com', 
  password: 'pass', 
  password_confirmation: 'pass',  
  account: new_account)
```

This fails with a `SQLite3::ConstraintException`, complaining that I'm not setting `account_id`.  It succeeds if I explicitly set the ID:

```
new_account = Account.create(name: 'AccountName')
new_user = User.create(
  email: 'foo@example.com', 
  password: 'pass', 
  password_confirmation: 'pass',  
  account_id: new_account.id)
```

My understanding is that the former approach should work - am I wrong about that, or am I just doing it wrong?  I'm on Rails 3.1.0, with Devise 1.4.7.

Comment: Something's wrong here, the first way works just fine for me using rails 3.1.0 and sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should not work the first way, as shown by your error. You must explicitly specify the id like you have done in the second example. :)